# "Could not find or load main class [Class name]"

Tags: java

I pasted this code from a tutorial site and compiled the code in CMD as well as attempting to run the code:

```
public class ExampleProgram {
  public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Since the PATH variable already existed, I added a path to the 'bin' file within the java file. I also added a new variable (CLASSPATH) and set the variable value to where I keep the `.class` file.

PS:

- The `.java` and the `.class` file are in the same folder
- No spelling or capitalization errors are made
- I did not add `.class` at the end where I try to run the code

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run the class? And don't use `CLASSPATH` it's deprecated. Use the `-cp` switch for the `java` command.

Comment: 1) Are you running from within the directory that contains the class file? 2) What command are you using to run?

Comment: I compiled like this:

`javac C:\Users\[Name]\Desktop\[File name]\ExampleProgram.java`

And I attempted to run the program like this:

`java ExampleProgram`

@a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: You are missing the `-cp` parameter, e.g. `java -cp . ExampleProgram` as described in the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html#win32-2c

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen 

1) Yes, the directory is correct. I copied the address from where the class file is located

2) 
`java ExampleProgram`
`-cp ExampleProgram`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

I've done what you said but it doesn't work. When I type:

`java -cp . ExampleProgram`

It says the same thing. I suspect that it has something to do with the PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have you java path set up done coorectly, run the following commands in order :
JavaProg is the name of the java file and your public class.

1.Suppose my .java file is in Desktop, then run the following command

```
cd Desktop
```

2. Compile it

```
javac JavaProg.java
```

3. Run it

```
java JavaProg
```

Comment: It works! Thanks!

By the way, does the command `cd` navigate to the subsequent directory?

Comment: Yes, cd would navigate you to any path you give. :)

Comment: I see! Thanks! :-D

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with "Netbeans" IDE and you want to run your program on command prompt(cmd),you should delete package statement or comment it by // marks. then use the following command:

`javac yourProgName.java`

```
java yourProgName
```

hope it be usefull

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep the .java file and remove the .class file.
2. Change to the directory of the .java file and compile the java file using the following command which will generate a .class file

   ```
   javac ExampleProgram.java
   ```
3. Run the program by

   ```
   java ExampleProgram
   ```

Comment: switch to the directory where the .java file is

Comment: I did. The directory is correct, I even copied the address from the file location itself.